# How to replace JSON value in kubectl output using go-template?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, go-templates

I have a configMap and I want to create a backup configMap by using the last applied configuration from that.

I use the following command to get the last applied configuration:

```
    kubectl get cm app-map -n app-space \
    -o go-template \
    --template='{{index .metadata "annotations" "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"}}' > backup.json
```

It returns something like this [the content of backup.json]:

```
{"kind":"ConfigMap","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"app-map","creationTimestamp":null},"data":{"app.yml":"xxxxxxxxx","config.yml":"yyyyyyyyy"}}
```

Now, I want my backup configMap to have a different name. So, I want to change the `.metadata.name` from `app-map` to `app-map-backup`.

Is there a way I can achieve that with `kubectl` and `-o go-template`? I want to have the name changed before I write it to the `backup.json` file.

I know I can do that using `jq` but I do not have permission to install `jq` on the server where I am using `kubectl`.

Comment: You can use sed: `kubectl -o go-template [...] | sed 's/"name":"app-map"/"name":"app-map-backup"/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this just using kubectl. But there are other ways.

You can download statically linked jq binary from [official jq website](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
chmod +x jq-linux64
```

and then you can use this binary like following:

```
kubectl -o go-template [...] | ./jq-linux64 ...
```

---

or you can use `sed`:

```
kubectl -o go-template [...] | sed 's/"name":"app-map"/"name":"app-map-backup"/'
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use [`kubectl bulk`](https://github.com/emreodabas/kubectl-plugins#kubectl-bulk-aka-bulk-action) plugin. The below command will replicate your config map

```
# get resource(s) and create with field(name) change 
kubectl bulk configmap app-map -n app-space create name app-mapp-backup
```

Kubectl bulk is very powerful to use, I suggest to check [samples](https://github.com/emreodabas/kubectl-plugins#kubectl-bulk-aka-bulk-action).